# Bind to string of self control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, converters

I have a custom converter that I want to make use of in xaml. The converter just places Admin if value is equal to 0, Cashier if it is equal to 2 etc..

Anyways this is what I am looking for.

```
 <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding 'I want to place the value in here', Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"></ComboBoxItem>
```

so that if I place:

```
 <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding '0', Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"></ComboBoxItem>
```

I am hoping it passes the value 0 to my converter. How can I achieve this?

---

I know I can cheat and do something like:

```
 <Label  Name="L1" Visiblity="hidden">0</Label>
 <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding, ElementName='L1', Path='Content' Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"></ComboBoxItem>
```

but that is to redundant

Comment: I don't understand your question, you do exactly what you have shown except actually place a binding (ie. Set the Path=, etc).  Are you unfamiliar with how to do the binding in general?

Comment: I have a converter that depends on logic such as the date and culture therefore I will like to make use of it in my code behind. I wanted to make use of it by binding it to listviews and also on labels....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since your implementation appears to be a hack anyway, you can just use another hack:

```
<ComboBoxItem Tag="0" 
              Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                                Path=Tag, 
                                Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}">
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you already accepted my first answer, but here's another method, which is probably more valid.

```
<Control ...
         xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

    <Control.Resources>
        <sys:Int32 x:Key="Zero">0</sys:Int32 >
    </Control.Resources>

    <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource Zero}, 
                                    Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}">

</Control>
```